# How To get value of last sublist using flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, display, sublist

Actually I'm on calculating crc using flutter. It's okey but I didn't get the expected result.
I want just the value of the last sublist not the values of all the sublists.
[output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKyBy.png)

In my case, I want just the last list : [ad].
this is my code:

```
 List getRandomBytes() {
    final listbytes = [
      0xDC,
      0x2E,
      0x20,
      0xF3,
      0x20,
      0x0E,
      0xBF,
      0x0A,
      0x31,
      0x39,
      0x31,
      0xF9,
      0x0F, //
      0x31,
      0x5D,
      0xFD,
      0xE4,
      0x19,
      0xB4
    ];
    List list3 = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {

      List list4 = [(listbytes[i] ^ listbytes[i + 1]).toRadixString(16)];
     
      list3 = List.from(list4);

   

      print(list3);

    
    }
    return list3;
  }
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want

```
[(listbytes[listbytes.length - 2] ^ listbytes[listbytes.length - 1]).toRadixString(16)]
```

I don't see the point of the loop really.

Comment: thank youu very much you are always helpful